# Unbroken words aren't forced to wrap inside heading tags; they overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Unbroken words are typically broken/forced to wrap when they grow longer than a line:

> LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliquaUtenimadminimveniamquisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequatDuisauteiruredolorinreprehenderitinvoluptatevelitessecillumdoloreeufugiatnullapariaturExcepteursintoccaecatcupidatatnonproidentsuntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborum

This declaration (`p { word-wrap: break-word; }`) isn't applied to headings; they can overflow:

> ## H1_Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdolor...
>
> ### H2_LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliquaU...
>
> #### H3_LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliquaUtenimadminimveniamquisnostrud...
>
> H4_unparagraphed_what_is_this_LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliquaUtenimadminimvenia...
>   
>   H5_actually_rendered_as_just_unparagraphed_LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliquaUtenin...
>   
>   H6_likewise_LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliquaUtenimadminimveniamquisnostrudexercit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been implemented now as the headings in the question now wrap.

> `.h1` through `.h6` all have `word-wrap: break-word` applied.